# R: boxplot of 2 columned table

Tags: r, boxplot

My input is:

```
4 a
2 a
3 a
5 b
4 b
1 c
5 c
8 c
```

I would like a boxplot of a, b, and c.

How do I convert the above into something I can boxplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `?boxplot` to find how to use the boxplot function.

For example

```
exampledf <- data.frame( val=c(4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 8), 
                         let=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c") )
boxplot(val ~ let, data=exampledf)
```

gives

[image]

though you really need more observations for each letter for this to be informative

Answer (score 1):

If your data are in the dataset `data1`, for example, you can use the following:

```
boxplot(data1[,1] ~data[,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ggplot package, where further refinements may be easier:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ddf)+geom_boxplot(aes(let, val))
```

[image]